# Typo in badge list for Electorate badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

First off, I apologize for the frequent meta posts, I'm not trying to be annoying - I'm just a curious person. :)

When I was looking at the list of badges I saw this typo:[image]

I think it is supposed to say "Vote on 600 **posts** and 25% or more of to total votes are on questions."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); unlike [Civic Duty](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/civic-duty), which counts votes on all posts, Electorate is specifically checking for votes on questions, not answers. The 'total' refers to all your votes on questions *and* answers; votes on questions need to be at least 25% of the total.

In the early days of Stack Exchange, people didn't vote that much on questions: [Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9508/295232). This badge was one of the ways to encourage people to vote more on questions; it was announced in response to [How to encourage voting on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8376/295232).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but you didn't quite answer my question. What I'm saying, is that this sentence does not make sense: "Vote on 600 questions, and 25% or more of to total votes are on questions." If you vote on 600 questions - 100% of those votes would have been on questions, yet the badge says 25%  should be on questions when 600 votes on questions is actually 100% amount of votes on questions.

Comment: Well, the word **posts** was bold, so I thought you thought *that* was the typo... I've edited my answer to indicate what the 'total' is referring to. Space is limited, and they have to take some shortcuts sometimes to indicate what a badge is for. There's an [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/295232) for all the details.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it clears it up. So, it is actually saying to vote on 2400 posts and 600 must be on questions?

Comment: No, you can get it with just 600 votes; if all of those are on questions, you satisfy both the first criterion and (because 100% of your votes are on questions) the second one.

Comment: But with exactly 600 votes on questions, you need to have 2400 or less total votes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! This helped.